# fill datalist html with array passed from .js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

hello guys i dont what i am doing wrong well i have a datebase with cities name and i wont to fill in a datalist html so i did 
res.render of the table to ejs file but when i try it its doesnt put anything inside the datalist so 
here what i have done :

test.ejs:

```
  <input name="car" list="anrede" />
<datalist id="anrede"></datalist>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var mycars = new Array();

    for (var j = 0; j< <%= adr %>.length; i++) 
    mycars[j]=(<%= adr %>)[j].place; 



  var options = '';

  for(var i = 0; i < mycars.length; i++)
    options += '<option value="'+mycars[i]+'" />';

  document.getElementById('anrede').innerHTML = options;
</script>
```

in the server.js

```
var sql2="SELECT place FROM `adresse`";
 db.query(sql2, function(err, results){
if(err){console.log("error");}else{
console.log(results.length);
            res.render('test.ejs',{adr:results});
```

Comment: Have you validated that the query in the sql2 variable is returning results (by querying the data directly)?

Comment: Yes the sql2  is workiing i tried console.log(results) and its printing on the consol { place: ‘paris’} {place : ‘london’} i think the problem ia in the ejs file when i try to acces the adr array i dont know if i am doing it the right way

Comment: Exactly what is adr? A one dimensional array of objects?